# mod rewrite condition fix to avoid partial word match

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Its probably very simple, but I can't make it work =/

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.+?)?$ adm.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Well, its suppose to send the user to the adm.php when there is a **localhost/admin** or **localhost/admin/anything** url, preserving the query string.

It works as expected, except for the fact it's matching any word that starts with 'admin', for example:

```
localhost/admin/news/list?page=1  =>  adm.php?route=news/list&page=1

localhost/adminbool/news/list?page=1  =>  adm.php?route=bool/news/list&page=1
```

Both of rewrite works, but that extra 'bool' messes everything in my routing process.

How can I make it respond only to a 'admin' exact match?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I guess im not clear enought. 
Here is the full .htaccess and a brief comment about how its suppose to work

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log|txt)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(adm/|app/|lib/|sys/) - [F,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!admin/?$)(.+?)/?$ index.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ adm.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

the index.php file refers to /app  (front-end)

the adm.php refers to the /adm (back-end)

the urls of the front-end has no prefix, while the back-end urls has the /admin/ prefix

**example:**

localhost/admin - **back-end**

localhost/admin/ - **back-end**

localhost/admin/news/list?order=date - **back-end**

localhost/ - **front-end**

localhost/admine - **front-end**

localhost/administration-whatever.html - **front-end**

localhost/admine123-anything.html - **front-end**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. Your regex is incorrect
2. You're not using helpful `QSA` flag.

Use this rule with correct regex and `QSA`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ adm.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(adm/|app/|lib/|sys/) - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ adm.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adm\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!admin/?$)(.+?)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Still not working.. the localhost/administration-rules.html page give me a not found error. I will edit the post to put the entire htaccess file.

Comment: Well my rules won't match `/administration-rules.html` but you still have that faulty rule in your code. Take out that rule with `RewriteRule ^(?!admin)(.+?)/?$ index.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` line (and 3 lies before it).

Comment: I need that line to rewrite everything else (the front-end). Thats why I need that to match /administration-rules.html to index.php and /admin to adm.php. Understand?

Comment: oh ok in that case your rule order is problem, let me provide you full .htaccess in my answer.

Comment: Same problem.. =(
anyway, I got a workaround with this:

 RewriteRule ^(?!admin/?$)(.+?)/?$ index.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Comment: ok great! updated my answer with that regex for visitors on this page.

Comment: Much appreciated, +1 to your question too. This will certainly help future visitors on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin[$|/*](.+?)?$ adm.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: cool, Almost there... :)
But I get an error when try it without the trailing slash.
localhost/admin
I also have problems in the front-end with pages like localhost/administration.html

Comment: Sorry for that. I have edited the answer. It was supposed to be `/*` not `/+`

Comment: `[$|/*]` - Do you have any idea what it does?

Comment: Yes regex is wrong. Symbols between `[ and ]` are matched literally and it is called character class. So `[$|/*]` will match a literal `$` OR `|` OR `/` OR `*`

Comment: Yes, should I have used `()` instead?